# MS Access 2013 textbox update macro

Tags: macros, ms-access-2013

What I am trying to accomplish:
Use button to open a form, filter the form, and set specific value to an unbound textbox in the opened form's header. There are multiple buttons being used open the same form and I would like this textbox to changed every time a specific button is clicked.

What I have done so far:
Used a macro to open the form and the "where" condition to filter the records. I also used "SetProperty" to change the value of the unbound textbox in the opened form's header depending on which button was clicked. When I do used the SetProperty option in the macro I get the error "The control name ... is misspelled or refers to a control that doesn't exist. Error 32004

I have verified numerous times that this is the correct name for the textbox and everything. I am pretty new to access and don't do VBA all that much so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[First Form and Macro for the "Physical Security" Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGY8b.jpg)

[Second form with error and unbound txt box I want to change to "Physical Security"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLFXJ.jpg)

Comment: Some code- snippets would be nice- you explain well what you did - but for programmers code is often the best explanation.

Comment: Well i didn't use any code, just the GUI for macros. How else could i get the code out there to explain or would screen shots help?

Comment: Screenshots are not warmly welcome here but in this case they most probably help to understand what you did and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Edited to include screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

A few Ideas to track down your problem:

- Maybe there's a problem with opening and (immediately) accessing the forms controls(?) You could try to fire a macro **from within the same from** that (only) changes the value of this text-box to make sure it *definitely* works there. Of course you'd want to make it work there if it failed before you'd go back to your original problem.
- Is the property called `value`? Could it be `text`?
- Are you sure you need to separate (all) hierarchies using `!`? Just by desperation: Maybe try using `Forms!frmVW.txtXY` or `Forms.frmVW.txtXY`

If that doesn't solve it:

It's often best to reduce your problem to it's very basics. Copy your application (**!!!!**) and radically delete unneeded stuff. Or start a short experiment from scratch (one or two forms, maybe only a button and a textbox, a macro, most probably not even a single Datatable/Source).

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out.

Comment: So I tried to do it within the form I have and it didn't work until I used no syntax and just the name of the txt box. So what I am wondering is how to reference the txt box control that's on another form. Example:
On formMain I am trying to run a macro from a button that will reference a txt box control on formCategory. The problem is I am trying to figure out what the full syntax is so I can reference it. If I am on the form it easily resolves when writing it, but when I am on another form I can't find it.

Comment: Your notation seems correct. But please doublecheck [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195841.aspx) for **different types of notation** - especially the very first portion BEFORE the examples. Do you happen to use some kind of Master-Forms or SubForms?

Comment: No I don't use a master or sub form in this project, just regular forms.